# How to create a release built of Win32 C++ app that uses lots of libs and not only included in VS environment headers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, deployment

So I created an app (with lots of help from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) and my friends). It compiles and runs on my machine (I tied to place it into different folders). VS created for me a debug older with my app : `HelloVideoStreaming.exe` some `HelloVideoStreaming.ilk` and `HelloVideoStreaming.pdb`. Problem is - when I try to run my app on another computer OS stups it from working saying that something about its parallel configuration is wrong.

I used Boost (used .lib libs), FFmpeg (Libs and DLLs ere linked into VS), OpenCV (I had it installed (installerfrom official open CV site) on my development computer) and OpenAL (I had it installed (installerfrom official open CV site) on my development computer).

Some of headers are included in VS some in project (via project properties)

How to make VS put all needed to deploy/run my app on other computers into one place? some folder like bin or somthing like that...

Comment: Please elaborate on this "parallel configuration is wrong"  Do you mean side-by-side deployment?

Comment: Try statically linking all your libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean "side-by-side" configuration is flagged as incorrect?  You have to make sure that the runtime libraries you built with are available on the target machine, also any third-party DLLs that you need, though it sounds like you tried to use all static libraries there.  For info on how to run VC++ apps from VS2010 on a machine that does not have VS 2010, see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=A7B7A05E-6DE6-4D3A-A423-37BF0912DB84&displaylang=en) - there are similar links for other compiler versions.

Please clarify the question if this is not the error you saw.

Comment: My guess is this is the situation.